# Need information about the Envisat satellite

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite

I am new to remote sensing and I want to know about sensor design of [Envisat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envisat) satellite. Can anybody help me or preferably direct me to some good references?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! I added a link to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best source of information on this now defunct satellite is through the European Space Agency (ESA).  Here is an ESA [link](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions/envisat) to the Envisat mission.  Pay particular attention to the *Key Resources* section of the web page--here you will find all the technical specifications of the instruments.